# Failed to download repository

Tags: 12.04, software-sources

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'univers/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a typo in your sources.list

Edit

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Look for the entry with univers

add an "e" to the end. Should be  **universe**